# How to print to a shared Konica Minolta pagepro 1580 MF printer?

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, windows-7

In my office all computers are Windows, except my PC runs Ubuntu 18.04.

We are connected to the same LAN where the IPv4 default gateway is 192.168.2.1, my IPv4 address is 192.168.2.10 and the Windows 7 PC to which the printer is connected has IPv4 address 192.168.2.100 . The printer is a [Konica Minolta Pagepro 1580 MF](https://bt.konicaminolta.in/laser-printers-2/pagepro-1580mf-specifications/) which doesn't have its own Ethernet port.

How do I connect/print with the printer through the Windows 7 PC that shares it to all users with my Ubuntu?

Comment: Page Pro 1580MF Drivers https://bt.konicaminolta.in/pro-1580mf-drivers/ ... → Linux https://o.cses.konicaminolta.com/file/Default.aspx?FilePath=DL/201311/19062354/pagepro1590mfcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb&_ga=2.51663083.317158267.1566219221-848021322.1566219221 ... → `pagepro1590mfcupswrapper-3.0.1-1.i386.deb`

Comment: Do your Windows PCs share through a Workgroup or a Domain? The latter requires a dedicated server, the former does not. Please click [edit] to answer; please don't use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

If the office computers are all in a Workgroup and not a Domain, go to the Windows 7 PC where connected to the printer, and select Devices and Printers.

Right click on the name of the printer you want to print to.

Left click on Printer Preferences. A pop-up window appears; click on the printer's Ports tab.

Uncheck **bi-directional printing** then save. Now you should be able to print to the printer from your Ubuntu PC.